# When having multiple posts expanded in the flag queue, deleting one will mark others as deleted

Tags: bug, design, moderator-tools

I just had two posts expanded in the mod tools and deleted one of them.

This resulted in both expanded posts being marked as deleted via the `deleted-answer` CSS class.

Comment: ...at least I assume that the fact that the posts were expanded had something to do with this.